# Android - Reading HTML5 localStorage data direct from Java

Tags: android, local-storage

I've got a simple Android app that has a WebView. The WebView is set to browse to a site which uses JavaScript's localStorage feature.

I've already got my WebSettings set to allow DomStorage:

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
ebSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

String dbPath = this.getApplicationContext().getDir("database", MODE_PRIVATE).getPath();        
webSettings.setDatabasePath(dbPath);
```

What I need is a way that my Java code can read a variable stored using the localStorage mechanism, ie.:

The JavaScript does this:

```
    var storage = window.localStorage;
    storage.setItem("name", "Hello World!");
```

How can I read the value of "name" from localStorage from Java code?

Comment: Not a single solution here works for me. Did you have any luck?

Answer (score 2):

yes possible to read localStorage value in java (Android).

use this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-nativestorage
that use native storage .

-for that we have to set value in cordova

```
    NativeStorage.setItem("reference", obj, setSuccess, setError);
    function setSuccess(obj){
    }
    function setError(obj){
    }
```

And In Anroid Java File to get this value :

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MainActivity", MODE_PRIVATE);
    System.out.println("********---------    shared pref values...   " +  sharedPreferences.getString("myid", "no value"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yourWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
      public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
        Log.d(tag, "That's my local storage value =" + message);
        return false;
      };
    });
(...)
    yourWebView.loadURL("javascript:alert(localStorage.getItem(\"name\"))");
```

Comment: This gives me: "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document."

Comment: @Onheiron I am also facing same issue. Did you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

in your activity

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(myInterface, "JSInterface");
```

Javascript interface class

```
class myInterface
{

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void getVariable(string fromLocalStorage)
    {
    //your code
    }

}
```

in javascript

```
window.JSInterface.getVariable(localStorage.getItem("variableName"))
```

Comment: This utilizes JavaScript for getting the value. I need my Android application to request the value from the browser, not the browser to initiate it. I can't call `webView.loadUrl` or `webView.evaluateJavaScript` using this method as it never actually does it.

Answer (score 0):

To write data :

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
     webView.evaluateJavascript("localStorage.setItem('"+ key +"','"+ val +"');", null);
} else {
     webView.loadUrl("javascript:localStorage.setItem('"+ key +"','"+ val +"');");
}
```

To read and alert data :

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
     webView.evaluateJavascript("window.alert(localStorage.getItem('"+ key +"'));", null);
} else {
     webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.alert(localStorage.getItem('"+ key +"'));");
}
```

And remember to enable JavaScript of Android `WebvView`

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```